# check if a field of type array contains an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Im using mongoose, I have the following data of `user` collection:

```
[{
    "_id": "1",
    "notes": [
        {
            "value": "A90",
            "text": "math"
        },
        {
            "value": "A80",
            "text": "english"
        },
        {
            "value": "A70",
            "text": "art"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "notes": [
        {
            "value": "A90",
            "text": "math"
        },
        {
            "value": "A80",
            "text": "english"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "3",
    "notes": [
        {
            "value": "A80",
            "text": "art"
        }
    ]
}]
```

and I have as a parameters the following array: `[ "A90", "A80" ]`
so I want to make a query to use this array to return only the records that have all the array items in the notes (value) table.
So for the example above it will return:

```
[{
    "_id": "1",
    "notes": [
        {
            "value": "A90",
            "text": "math"
        },
        {
            "value": "A80",
            "text": "english"
        },
        {
            "value": "A70",
            "text": "art"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "notes": [
        {
            "value": "A90",
            "text": "math"
        },
        {
            "value": "A80",
            "text": "english"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I tried the following find query:

```
{ "notes": { $elemMatch: { value: { $in: valuesArray } } }}
```

but it returns a record even if just one element in valuesArray exist.

Comment: Did you try [find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) ?

Comment: i tried the following : `{ "notes": { $elemMatch: { value: { $in: valuesArray } } }}` but it return a record even if just an element in `valuesArray` exist, i want to return a record if all the element in `valuesArray` exists in `note`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find exactly match array or having all value of array in MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735439/find-exactly-match-array-or-having-all-value-of-array-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out to be quite easy:

```
find({ "notes.value": { $all: arrayValues } })
```